# My 15S BMS of LiFePO4 battery stack outputs 15.9 V (the entire pack measures 48 V)

Tags: lithium-ion, bms, lifepo4

I have a LiFePO4 stack of 15S and 3P configuration.

Everything was working fine until I broke the pack and divided it into two packs of 8S and 7S, and connected both via jumper wires. Now the pack measures the same voltage (48 V) as before but my BMS outputs a lower voltage (15.9 V).

It's a daly non-smart BMS which is a common port configuration. Kindly help me troubleshooting it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Thanks for the suggestions and answers, it really motivated me to think from a different perspective and now it's working.

1. I checked all the balance connections and it was fine.
2. To activate the BMS, I have tried short circuiting the input (blue) and output (black) of BMS but it didn't work.
3. **Finally even when the input from the pack is disconnected from the battery (the blue wire in the picture) the output was the same 15.9 V. I was shocked, so I short-circuited the positive of the battery pack (red) with the BMS input (blue), and then it worked.**

It was a eureka moment, but I still wonder how it worked?

Comment: Have you verified that you rewired it correctly and all connections are sound? What happens if you try to charge the pack?

Comment: yes @BruceAbbott i have rewired it correctly and the pack voltage is 48 volt but if i tried to measure the voltage output at BMS then it shows 15.9 and its not charging too.

Comment: These problems are hard to diagnose at a distance as there is nothing to go on except for your description (which essentially tells us nothing is wrong but it still doesn't work). Is the 48V measured directly at the input of the BMS? What about balancing connections (I'm assuming those are present in a 15S system), have you checked those? Might the BMS have been damaged during the rebuild? Did you measure the 15.9V at the output when there was load on the battery or when nothing was connected?

Comment: Some BMSes need some ritual to start them after assembly. A Daly smart BMS in my posession needs the charger running for a couple of seconds to start.

Comment: _15S and 3P configuration_. Do you mean 3P15S? That is, 3 cells in parallel to form a block, then 15 such blocks in series?

Comment: Please post pictures of your battery, so we can see how you connected it.

Comment: I have tried running my charger for so long but bms doesn’t allow any amps to flow.

Comment: Yes @davide Andrea the configuration is correct . I have posted the pictures as per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you rewired it correctly and didn't damage the BMS there are 2 possible causes I can think of:-

1. One or more cells have abnormal voltage which is causing the BMS to shut down.

Measure the voltage across each cell at the BMS connector. If any are markedly different from 3.2 V then either they have abnormal voltage (which may require charging/discharging those cells individually to balance them, or replacing faulty cells) or the wiring/connection is faulty.

2. The BMS shut down when it lost power while the pack was broken apart. When this happens some BMS chips need to be 'activated' by applying an external charging voltage.

If the charger is a simple CV/CC type then simply connecting it to the battery should activate the BMS. However more sophisticated chargers often won't charge until they see a good pack voltage - which is not present because the BMS is shut down! If this is the case then you may need to momentarily apply external voltage from a power supply of appropriate voltage (~45-48 V) with current-limiting via a series resistor or current limit on the power supply.

Comment: Should I add the charger voltage 54.6volt and 6 amps directly to battery pack while by passing the connected bms?

Comment: Charging the pack directly won't have any effect on the BMS. Having seen your photos I am extremely suspicious of the BMS wiring. It would only take one bad connection or two wires swapped to stop the BMS from working. What voltage does your charger put out when not connected to the battery?

Comment: charger outputs its desired voltage.

Comment: In your non-answer you said _"so i short circuited the positive of the battery pack (red) with the BMS input (Blue wire) , then it worked."_- So it was an activation issue. But... the blue wire is connected to battery negative, right? So you shorted out the battery! ???

Comment: No I disconnected the bms from the pack then I short circuited the bms alone with the positive terminal of the battery pack I saw some sparks then everything work fine.

Comment: Did you also disconnect all the balance wires and black wire? If not then you may have damaged the BMS. You should test the BMS to make it still cuts off if the pack or any call voltage is too high or low. Disconnecting one balance wire will probably be enough for this test, as it should cause the BMS to think that cell has no voltage. Also measure all the cell voltages to make sure the balancer function is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The BMS is damaged. And this is how it was damaged (based on experience with such batteries and familiarity that specific Daly BMS).

In order:

1. You split the battery into two sections
2. You connected the battery to the big cables on the BMS
3. You connected the "balance" connector to the BMS
4. You connected the cables between the two section

At step #3, the BMS blew. That's because the capacitors across the BMS were initially discharged. Therefore the entire battery voltage, negated (-48 V) appeared across the two balance wires, one for the most positive cell in the section sitting flat on the table, one for the most negative cell in the up-right section. That voltage blew the BMS.

That's why it's a bad idea to use a BMS like that one when managing a split battery pack. Instead, you should use a BMS that has two mutually isolated banks.

Step 4 should have occurred before you connected the BMS balance wires.